# How do I define multiple factories in my services.js file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two arrays of data that I want to define in my services.js and then pass into my controller. I tried setting up two factories but it says that:

```
Module 'myApp.services' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

I do not get this error when only one factory is defined.

I am also wondering if it's ok/possible to define two separate sets of data in one factory.

```
//services.js

'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.services', [])

.factory('myProperties', function() {

    var myProperties = [
        {
            'name': '3 Bedroom Fixer Upper',
            'city': 'Santa Rosa',
            'state': 'CA',
            'date_added': '2/3/14'
        },
        {
            'name': '2 Bedroom Condo',
            'city': 'Vallejo',
            'state': 'CA',
            'date_added': '4/10/20'
        },
        {
            'name': 'Sophias Apartment',
            'city': 'Salt Lake City',
            'state': 'UT',
            'date_added': '2/5/14'
        }
    ];

    //return the array here
    return myProperties
};

.factory('buyProperties', function() {

    var buyProperties = [
        {
            'name': '3 Bedroom Fixer Upper',
            'city': 'Santa Rosa',
            'state': 'CA',
            'date_added': '2/3/14'
        },
        {
            'name': '2 Bedroom Condo',
            'city': 'Vallejo',
            'state': 'CA',
            'date_added': '4/10/20'
        },
    ];

    //return the array here
    return buyProperties
});
```

Comment: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.javascript.angularjs/11168 seems to be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the semi colon after the first factory definition and add a closing bracket:

```
angular.module('myApp.services', [])
    .factory('myProperties', function() {
 })
    .factory('buyProperties', function() {
 });
```

Module and factory definitions allow chaining.

Comment: There was a missing bracket in there as well.